# Linq - Removing a Row

Tags: c#, linq, xaml

I have created a local DB using the empty designer model, I've added the properties and the data. On the startup of my program the information is coming into the grid meaning that the DB is working fine.

I have a button when clicked it will read the selected item from the gridbox and remove it from the database. However when I try this I get the following error:

> Additional information: Non-static method requires a target.

This is the code I am using:

```
    private void btnRemoveManager_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DatagridManagerDisplay.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            ManagerTBL selected = DatagridManagerDisplay.SelectedValue as ManagerTBL;

            var removeManager = from manager in db.ManagerTBLs
                                where manager.ManagerName == selected.ManagerName
                                select manager;

            db.ManagerTBLs.RemoveRange(removeManager);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Repeat the on window loaded method to refresh the grids
            Window_Loaded(sender, e);

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a team from the league");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have to remove one row at one time then why you using RemoveRange()?

Comment: When I use the remove method I get the following error:
cannot convert from system.Linq.IQueryable<PremAssignment.ManagerTBL> to PremAssignment.ManagerTBL

Comment: @ZaheerUlHassan I would like to use the remove function if that would make it easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SingleOrDefault` to get a single object matching your criteria, and then pass that to the `Remove` method of your EF table.

```
private void btnRemoveManager_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbxManagerDisplay.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            ManagerTBL selected = lbxManagerDisplay.SelectedValue as ManagerTBL;
            var removeManager = db.ManagerTBLs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ManagerName == selected.ManagerName); //returns a single item.

           if (removeManager != null)
            {
              db.ManagerTBLs.Remove(removeManager );
              db.SaveChanges();
            }    

            // Repeat the on window loaded method to refresh the grids
            Window_Loaded(sender, e);

        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a team from the league");
        }
    }
```

Hope it Helps!

Comment: getting an error on both: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Comment: Also just some questions: should I remove the query and the selected? is the managerTBLobj the same as the selected

Comment: is selected contain complete object items?

Comment: Just seeing that now, the selected contains null. I dont understand why though, I have used this before and it has worked....

Comment: that's why it not getting the object items from db. you need to get the selected row id and then get the object against that id to remove.

Comment: what you put in lbxManagerDisplay.SelectedValue? row id or complete object?

Comment: In the 'lbxManagerDisplay' I have used linq to select the managers name, nationality, team and trophy count and put that into a datagrid. Nothing is coming into the .selectedValue at the moment, I am trying to fix this through the selectionchanged

Comment: first of all you need to bind the **id** against each row and onselectedchanged event you get that **id** in your method and then further this code.

Comment: [Check This link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-GridView-using-LINQ-to-SQL-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `RemoveAll` like this.

```
ManagerTBL selected = (ManagerTBL)lbxManagerDisplay.SelectedItem;

if (selected != null)
{
    db.ManagerTBLs.RemoveAll(mng => mng.ManagerName == selected.ManagerName);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yea, the problem I am having is that the 'selected' is null after I try to put that case of manager into the variable.
I dont want to remove all of the DB just the case of the manager that was selected

Comment: the lbxManagerDisplay is actually a datagrid

Comment: Yeah I have tried that, the 'selected' is still null